# Rename an APK file based on a textfile contents using Shell Scripting on a Mac

Tags: android, shell, unix, scripting, rename

I am trying to take a file and rename it based on text i have in a file. Basically i have an android APK that i want to rename to name_version.apk I am using AAPT to dump the version number of the apk into a version.txt file and so the output of cat version.txt looks like this
1.0b17

So how would I go about using either cat (or some other shell command) to rename MyApp.apk to MyApp_v1.0b17.apk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use backticks to capture the output from `cat` into a string, like this.

```
`cat version.txt`
```

From there, you can make a simple `mv` command with that in the arguments.

```
mv "MyApp.apk" "MyApp_`cat version.txt`.apk"
```